# Bidding History Table Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have created a bidding system where the current bid will update the table each time a bid is placed, the CustID will update accordingly too.

In order for the customer to view their bidding history, I have created a bidHistory table. The problem I am facing for an unknown reason is the CustID is changing in all of the rows rather than just the most recent.

```
DROP TRIGGER bidHistory;
CREATE TRIGGER bidHistory
AFTER UPDATE ON bid
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO bidHistory (BidID, CustID, TimeStamp) VALUES (new.BidID, new.CustID, now());
```

Any help would be great, and thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, managed to figure my problem out, it wasn't in fact an issue with the trigger but rather the constraints cascading on update.

Just putting this out there for anyone else making this same silly mistake.